# C - adding a string to an existing array

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to add a string to an existing array but I'm a bit stuck. I have to check if *word is already in the array and if it isn't, then I have to add it to the array. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int insert(char *word, char *Table[], int n)
{
    //char *word is the string to be added, *char Table[] is array of strings
    //int n is the return value, which is the number of elements in *Table[]
    int counter = 0
    while(*Table[counter]) //while at Index counter
    {
        if strcmp((*Table[counter], *word) == 0) //if *word at Index counter is true
        {
            return n; //return the amount of strings in the array
            break; //terminate the while-loop
        else
        {
            counter++; //increment the counter to check the next index
        }
    }
}
```

so I've hopefully successfully checked if *word is already in the array, but how do I add it if it isn't? Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try this, it runs fine and adds to array of strings.
   For a beginner it is better to start simple.
   Here we start we 5 strings of length 99
   I left you some work to do. Have fun.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSTRINGS 5
#define LENSTRING 99

int insert( char word[], char Table[][99] )  // removed n , could not understand the need.
{
  int counter = 0;

  while ( counter < MAXSTRINGS && strlen( Table[counter] ) )    //while at Index counter and string not empty
  {

    if ( strcmp( Table[counter], word ) == 0 )  //if string was found
    {
      return counter;           //return string position  in array of strings
      break;            //terminate the while-loop
    }
    else
    {
      counter++;        //increment the counter to check the next index
    }

  }// endwhile
  strcpy( Table[counter], word );
  printf( "\n added at %d", counter );
  return(counter);
}

int main(  )
{
  char Table[MAXSTRINGS][LENSTRING];
  int i = 0;
  int answer = 0;

  for ( i = 0; i < MAXSTRINGS; i++ )
    memset( Table[i], '\0', LENSTRING );

  strcpy( Table[0], "a test" );
  strcpy( Table[1], "another test" );

  answer = insert( "test", Table);
  if ( !answer )
    printf( "\n already in file" );
  else
    printf( "\nadded record to position %d in array ", answer );

  getchar(  );

}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `break;` after a return statement?

Comment: Instead of the memset loop, `= { 0 };` is simpler and less prone to errors

Comment: Your code writes off the end of the table if the table is full

Comment: The `if ( !answer )` test is hard to understand, since `0`, `1`, `2` etc. all mean that the string was already in the table at the given position

Answer (score -1):

First off where you have

```
if strcmp((*Table[counter], *word) == 0) //if *word at Index counter is true
        {
            return n; //return the amount of strings in the array
            break;
```

The `break` is useless because once you `return n` the function will stop.

Secondly lets think about it, if we never find word in `*Table[]` then the while loop should eventually exit right? So the case where we dont find `*word` is if we exit the while loop

EDIT: Your compiler should have complained about this function because its possible you exit the while loop and then the function doesnt return anything but you specify that it returns `int` if your compiler didnt say anything you need to turn on compiler warnings or use a different compiler.

Try something similar to this. This is untested code so you may still need to play with it.

```
while(*Table[counter]) //while at Index counter
    {
        if strcmp((*Table[counter], *word) == 0) //if *word at Index counter is true
        {
            return n; //return the amount of strings in the array
            break; //terminate the while-loop
        else
        {
            counter++; //increment the counter to check the next index
        }
    }
    *Table[counter] = *word; //Add word to the next available spot in the array
    return 0;
}//End function
```

Comment: if we never find the word then I want to add that word to the array. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: @donutjuice Well you would need to make sure the array is not yet full. You would then need to add a statement at the end of the function something like `*Table[counter] = *word`. Also look at my answer again I added an edit for another problem

Comment: what would you change in my code then? I'm having trouble following your explanation. I'm quite a beginner in C...

Comment: `*Table[counter]` is a `char` and so not a valid argument to `strcmp` which expects a pointer.  You should really test your code before posting if not experienced enough to be able to write correct code withtout testing.